# Ruby: alias_method for module static method

Tags: ruby, alias-method

Given this module

```
module Test
  def self.foo(v)
    puts "Test.foo with #{v}"
  end
end
```

The following doesn't work

```
module Test  
  alias_method :bar, :foo
  # ...
end
```

although it works for instance methods. I get following error

```
NameError: undefined method `foo' for module `Test'
```

My goal is to override **self.foo** as following

```
def self.foo(v)
  self.bar(v + " monkey patched")
end
```

Is there a way to alias static method?

Comment: I thought you simply wanted to alias a class method with another class method (I provided an answer that does that). However, I don't understand your comment your goal to override `foo` in a particular way. Could you please clarify that, preferably with an edit.

Comment: So, there's existing module Test, whose method **foo** I want to override. But I want to use the existing implementation and just slightly change, e.g. augmenting the arguments. Your solution works for me actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Test.singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :bar, :foo)
Test.bar("cat")
  #=> "Test Foo with cat"
```